PHP warning that built-in PHP function is an undeclaired variable... why? what am I doing wrong?
Okay so quite a few years ago, I was trying to teach myself PHP, and got okay-ish at making bad but functional code... that was all I needed as I just wanted to build stuff for myself to run on a localhost only. I'm still in that place where I just want stuff for me on my computer, it doesn't need to be clean or secure or anything like that just functional. So recently I tried reviving a project (code I downloaded from GitHub before Microsoft acquired it... aka it's really old and not available anymore)
Now here's the kicker... when I go to run the code I keep getting warnings like:

Warning: Undefined variable $error_reporting in C:\xampp\htdocs\Playground\FileManager\Test_003\index.php on line 80

Problem is, error_reporting (no dollar sign in code) isn't a variable, it's a PHP function... so what gives?
here's the relevant code:
switch ($error_reporting){
    case 0: error_reporting(0); @ini_set("display_errors",0); break;
    case 1: error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR); @ini_set("display_errors",1); break;
    case 2: error_reporting(E_ALL); @ini_set("display_errors",1); break;
}

I'm thinking I could fix it with $error_reporting = "";, but that causes it to throw a hissy-fit (tons more warnings, and no page loading)... so what should I do?

Where is $error_reporting defined in your code?

Which is line 80?

"(no dollar sign in code)" - no? switch ($error_reporting) - looks very much like dollar sign to me. That would not perhaps happen to be line #80?

The warning lied about the line number... it said it was on line 80 which is the   case 0: error_reporting(0); @ini_set("display_errors",0); break; line... I'm blind and failed to look up one line. LOL my bad... where is it defined? it's not, thx. Can I accept these three replies as my answer?

It's not clear what the purpose of this code should even be. Your code should not have any other setting than error_reporting(E_ALL);. You could exclude notices and deprecations, but it's not recommended. All other error types must be included. Try just removing all of this code.

As a side note, here - if this exact code was behaving differently last time you ran it, it may be because something else has chanced since then. For example, if this is a new/different PHP installation. The default error reporting settings in PHP have changed somewhat over time, and can also change depending on the way each installation is configured. It's possible this error always existed, but whether or not it is displayed to you by default is a separate matter.

Error reporting is a built-in function in PHP. You are trying to use it as a variable, which is why PHP is returning an error for an undefined function.
I am not sure why you are using a switch, but if you are trying to report all errors you could use:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_reporting.asp
This link has more information on how to handle error reporting.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
